# Magento Attribute Drop Down Search

Tags: magento, attributes, php

hope someone can advise?

I need to create a dropdown search that has 4 fields in magento, this needs to display in the left.phtml template file.

It also needs to have a 'go' button or 'search' button at the bottom of the dropdowns this then posts results to a search page.

Can anyone offer me any pointers, things to look at?, help?

Thanks!

Comment: i think your talking about search extension.you can do it by studying the advance search method using attributes based.

Comment: ok thanks will take a look, do you know of any good links that show this?

Comment: if you are asking about extension.look at this extension http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-year-make-model-attributes.html.If your requirement match , i can guide you further.

Comment: got it working just customising advanced search and display in left.phtml.